# What's the right way of unit-testing a python class?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm not sure what's the best way to build independent unit tests on methods of a  python class. Here is a trivial example:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data

  def myMethod(self):
    #do something
    return True
```

I'm building unit tests like this:

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_init(self):
    mydata = mock.Mock()
    c = MyClass(mydata)
    self.assertEqual(c.data, mydata)

  def test_myMethod(self):
    mydata = mock.Mock()
    c = MyClass(mydata)
    self.assertTrue(c.myMethod())
```

OK, this is very trivial... but the point is: `test_myMethod()` depends on  `__init__` because I have to instantiate the object itself: it isn't really isolated. The only way that has come to my mind to solve this issue is mocking the object itself... but how can I test a real method on a mocked object?

I know that in real world a perfect isolation could be impossible, but I'm curious to know if there are better ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes down to what you want to test and in how much granularity. For example, what exactly is the assertion that `c.data` equals the data you have just assigned in the previous line actually test? It tests a single line of practical code, and it tests a rather unimportant implementation detail. This is probably much too granular to bother.

You want to ensure that your object behaves as it should overall. That means you want to test that you can instantiate it, and then assert that

1. if you instantiate it with data A and then call method B the result will be C
2. if you instantiate it with data D and then call method B the result will be E
3. if you try to instantiate it with incorrect data that an error is thrown

Your tests should focus on *object behaviour*, not on testing implementation minutiae. Write your tests so you could drop in an alternative object implementing the same behaviour in a different way without breaking your tests. You are writing that class to get some specified tasks done; test that your implementation can get those tasks done, not *how* it gets them done.

Exempli gratia:

```
def test_worksWithDataA(self):
    c = MyClass({'some': 'data'})
    self.assertTrue(c.myMethod())

def test_worksWithDataB(self):
    c = MyClass({'other': 'data'})
    self.assertFalse(c.myMethod())

def test_rejectsDataC(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
        MyClass(None)
```

You only need to mock something if you need to pass a dependency, but that dependency is too complex to instantiate for the sake of the test. As long as your data is just a `dict`, there's no need to mock it. If your data is a complex type on its own, then you may want to mock it in order to test `MyClass`, without getting tangled up in having to test that other class at the same time. When mocking, again, mock the expected *behaviour* of that class; as a rule of thumb, all the behaviour you're asserting your class has using unit tests can be mocked elsewhere.

Comment: So you say that it isn't a good idea, in general, to build a test for the `__init__` method?

Comment: Well, above we're testing that the `__init__` method raises an exception on wrong data... I'm saying you must test **behaviour**, regardless of where that behaviour resides. Describe the behavioural attributes your class must have in a few bullet points, write it on paper. *"The class must do X, Y and Z, that's its purpose of existence."* Then write those as tests. You'll want to be executing and exercising all lines of code in the class during those tests ("100% code coverage"); but your tests must not necessary focus on testing specific lines of code.

Comment: It isn't a good idea for the most time to test the certain implementation, as it can change multiple times during development process. What you should test is the functionality/behavior. You can think of it as a black-box testing. Your test class doesn't know what the test subject is build from, it only tests the result of it's work.

Comment: @Zac If that helps: pretend someone else gave you that class in a compiled form and you have no access to the source code. You have no idea how it does something, all you know is that you want it to do something.